# Exporting a xml document from sql 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

All

I have very little experience of xml, so please be gentle.

The situation is we use an application called dataswitch to take xml and process it into our ERP system via business objects.

The output I am trying to recreate is as follows from a sample xml document.

```
**<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252" ?> 
- <IssueDetails Language="05" CssStyle="" DecFormat="1" DateFormat="01" Role="01" Version="6.0.000">**
- <Item>
  <Job>00000121</Job> 
  <NonStocked>N</NonStocked> 
  <Warehouse>RM</Warehouse> 
  <StockCode>BBMB100</StockCode> 
  <Line>00</Line> 
  <QuantityToIssue>1.000</QuantityToIssue> 
  </Item>
  </IssueDetails>
```

So far I have worked on the For xml Path method to build my query and used the sp from [Phil Factor](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/reading-and-writing-files-in-sql-server-using-t-sql/) to [write the output](https://www.simple-talk.com/code/WorkingWithFiles/spWriteStringTofile.txt)

So far I have been successful creating an xml document which opens in the browser (many tries required!)

This is the output I have managed to create, please note the top lines are different

```
**<IssueDetails xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">**
- <Item>
  <Job>00044816</Job> 
  <NonStocked>N</NonStocked> 
  <Warehouse>C2</Warehouse> 
  <StockCode>FG00707</StockCode> 
  <Line>00</Line> 
  <QuantityToIssue>400.000000000</QuantityToIssue> 
  </Item>
- <Item>
  <Job>00044816</Job> 
  <NonStocked>N</NonStocked> 
  <Warehouse>C2</Warehouse> 
  <StockCode>FG00707</StockCode> 
  <Line>00</Line> 
  <QuantityToIssue>10.000000000</QuantityToIssue> 
  </Item>
</IssueDetails>
```

So my question is how do I get the top line in my output to be the same as the sample output?

My procedure is listed below

```
Declare 
    @XML_1 varchar (max),
    @myXML varchar(max),
    @myFile varchar (30),
    @Path varchar (100)

set @XML_1=''
set @myFile ='MaterialIssuesTest.xml'
set @Path='D:\Temp\'


--Query database for materials
Set @XML_1 =@XML_1 + (  SELECT WJM.[Job]

            ,Case when WJM.[Warehouse]='**' then 'Y' else 'N' end as NonStocked
            ,WJM.[Warehouse]
            ,rtrim(LP.StockCode) as StockCode
            ,WJM.[Line]
            ,[UnitQtyReqd]*LP.LQtyComplete as QuantityToIssue
            FROM [SysproCompanyR].[dbo].[WipJobAllMat] WJM 
            inner join CHC_Production.LabPostsAtMileOps LP On WJM.Job=LP.Job 
            Where WJM.Job in ('00044816')and (WJM.OperationOffset > LP.PrevOp
            and WJM.OperationOffset<LP.LOperation)
            FOR XML Path ('Item'),ROOT ('IssueDetails'), ELEMENTS XSINIL 
            )
set @myXML = LTRIM(rtrim(@XML_1))
--Debug print xml
Print @myXML
--Output xml to document
execute     dbo.spWriteStringToFile @myXML, @Path, @myFile
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

To get you first line, which is a child element of the main body you need to do a sub query like what I have done below. To get the attributes you need to name them with the @ symbol, again in my example (formatting changes to aid me setting it out!):

```
SET @XML_1 =@XML_1 + 
    (  
    SELECT WJM.[Job],
           (
           SELECT '' AS '@Language',
                  '' AS '@CssStyle',
                  '' AS '@DecFormat',
                  '' AS '@DateFormat',
                  '' AS '@Role',
                  '' AS '@Version'
           FROM   YOURTABLENAME YTN
           WHERE  YTN.[SOMEFIELD] = WJM.[SOMEFIELD]
           FOR    XML PATH(''), TYPE
           ) AS 'IssueDetails'

          ,Case when WJM.[Warehouse]='**' then 'Y' else 'N' end as NonStocked
          ,WJM.[Warehouse]
          ,rtrim(LP.StockCode) as StockCode
          ,WJM.[Line]
          ,[UnitQtyReqd]*LP.LQtyComplete as QuantityToIssue
    FROM  [SysproCompanyR].[dbo].[WipJobAllMat] WJM 
    INNER JOIN CHC_Production.LabPostsAtMileOps LP ON WJM.Job = LP.Job 
    WHERE   WJM.Job IN ('00044816') AND (WJM.OperationOffset > LP.PrevOp
        AND WJM.OperationOffset<LP.LOperation)
    FOR XML Path ('Item'), ROOT ('IssueDetails'), ELEMENTS XSINIL 
    )
```

I don't know where the data is coming from, so you will have to fill in the table name and the `WHERE` clause to join it to the data that you already have. That is assuming the data is a child of the data that you have already provided.

Bare in mind the syntax might not be quite correct as I am doing this from memory and there are several different variations to get this result.

Comment: that is great the data from the sub query you provided is currently static so even easier to do! Many Thanks I will give it a go over lunch

Comment: Let me know how you get on with it. Any problems and I will try and sort out the syntax for you.